# Complex Print Statement

Tags: json, java-8, jackson

So far what i have:

**A directory which has two folders:**

1. ..\Data\BeforeModern
2. ..\Data\AfterModern

Each Folder(BeforeModern and AfterModern) has 4 JSON files namly (**AU,UK,US,IND**);

The **Json** file contain a particular Fieldname(Language) which is of My interest.

for example in AU JSON in BeforeModern the lang is

```
Language["English","Spanish"]
```

while in AFterModern the lang is something Like this:

```
Language["English","Spanish","Arabic"]
```

I want to print the result like the below:

```
         **BeforeModern**            **AfterModern**
            English                     English
AU :        Spanish                     Spanish
                                        Urdu
```

**My approach till now:**

```
for (File beforeFile: new File(locationPath).listFiles()) {
            File afterFile= new File(locationPath.replace("BeforeModern", "AfterModern") + "\\" + locFile.getName());

            if (afterfile.exists()) {
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                JsonNode tree1 = mapper.readTree(beforeFile); //Parse Specific JSON from BeforeModern Location
                JsonNode tree2 = mapper.readTree(afterFile); //Parse Specific JSON from AfterModern Location
                if (tree1.has("Language") && tree2.has("Language")) {
                    JsonNode sup_loc = tree1.get("Language");
                    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
                    sup_loc.forEach(l -> list1.add(l.asText()));
                    JsonNode sup_rent = tree2.get("Language");
                    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
                    sup_rent.forEach(l -> list2.add(l.asText()));
                    int rows = Math.max(list1.size(), list2.size());


                    Map<String, String> hash= new HashMap<>();
                    for (int i=0;i<rows;i++){
                        hash.put(list1.get(i),list2.get(i));
                    }
                    Map<String,Map<String,String>> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put(beforeFile.getName(),hash);
                    map.entrySet().forEach((k)->System.out.println(k.getKey()+"                                                "+k.getValue()));
                    //hash.entrySet().forEach((k)->System.out.println(k.getKey()+"                         "+k.getValue()));
                    System.out.println("________________________________________________________________________________");
```

Comment: What is the `JSON` structure? Could you show an example `JSON` content?

Comment: `{
    "Name": "ABC.com",
    "Developer": "DDD",
    "Language": [
        "ENGLISH",
        "SPANISH",
        "URDU"
    ]
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to print the `AU :` on the middle line of the list of languages, you need to calculate the index of the middle line.

In order to print the two lists of language names as columns, you need to find the length of the longest language name in the first column, whose column header is `**BeforeModern**`. Then you can use method `printf()` of class `PrintStream` to make sure that the `**AfterModern**` list also appears as a column. In the below code snippet, `longest` is an `int` representing the length of the longest language name and `before` is a `String` containing a language name in the first column and `after` is a `String` representing the corresponding language name in the second column.

```
System.out.printf("%-" + longest + "s  %s%n", before, after);
```

And print the lists via a loop so that you know when to print the `AU :`. In the below code, `maxLines` is an `int` which is the number of elements in the larger of the two lists of language names and `middle` is an `int` containing the index of the line where `AU :` needs to be printed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxLines; i++) {
    if (middle == i) {
        System.out.print("AU : ");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("     ");
    }
}
```